# Why is R's hamming function different from Matlab's?

Tags: r, function, matlab, signal-processing

Why does the `hamming` function in R give different values to the function of the same name in Matlab?

Matlab:

```
hamming(76)

    0.0800
    0.0816
    0.0864
    0.0945
    0.1056
    0.1198
```

R:

```
library(gsignal)
hamming (76)

0.08695652 0.08851577 0.09318288 0.10092597 0.11169213 0.1254078
```

Comment: What package is `hamming` from? It is not a base function. What function are you using in Matlab? Editing your question to explain in more detail what exactly you are doing may get you better, faster help - good luck!

Comment: in matlab `hamming` is to design hamming windows for filters. What do you mean `hamming` in R?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Algorithms

They are following different formulas ***(same format but different coefficients)*** to compute Hamming windows

- In `R`, it is

> (25/46) - (21/46) * cos(2 * pi * (0:n)/N)

which can be viewed when typing `hamming`

```
> hamming
function (n, method = c("symmetric", "periodic")) 
{
    if (!isPosscal(n) || !isWhole(n) || n <= 0)
        stop("n must be an integer strictly positive")
    method <- match.arg(method)
    if (method == "periodic") {
        N <- n
    }
    else if (method == "symmetric") {
        N <- n - 1
    }
    else {
        stop("method must be either 'periodic' or 'symmetric'")
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        w <- 1
    }
    else {
        n <- n - 1
        w <- (25/46) - (21/46) * cos(2 * pi * (0:n)/N)
    }
    w
}
```

- In `MATLAB`, the algorithm is (see https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hamming.html)

[image]

and ***there are some precision difference for two coefficients***

```
> 25/46
[1] 0.5434783
> 21/46
[1] 0.4565217
```

## Analysis

Two reasons that make the differences

1. in `gsignals::hamming`, if you choose `symmetric` by default, you will have `N <- n-1` and `n <- n-1`, that means the equivalent to Matlab's `hamming` should be `hamming(76+1)`
2. the approximations `0.54` and `0.46` in Matlab contribute to the deviation from R's version.

## Tests with Handmade Implementations

We can implement `hamming` functions according to formulas from `MATLAB` and `R`, respectively, e.g.,

```
hamMatalb <- function(n) 0.54 - 0.46 * cos(2 * pi * (0:n) / n)
hamR <- function(n) 25 / 46 - 21 / 46 * cos(2 * pi * (0:n) / n)
```

and then run

```
> hamMatalb(75) # the same as obtained by hamming(76) in MATLAB
 [1] 0.08000000 0.08161328 0.08644182 0.09445175 0.10558687 0.11976909
 [7] 0.13689893 0.15685623 0.17950101 0.20467443 0.23219992 0.26188441
[13] 0.29351967 0.32688382 0.36174283 0.39785218 0.43495860 0.47280181
[19] 0.51111636 0.54963351 0.58808309 0.62619540 0.66370312 0.70034314
[25] 0.73585847 0.77000000 0.80252824 0.83321504 0.86184514 0.88821773
[31] 0.91214782 0.93346756 0.95202741 0.96769718 0.98036697 0.98994790
[37] 0.99637276 0.99959650 0.99959650 0.99637276 0.98994790 0.98036697
[43] 0.96769718 0.95202741 0.93346756 0.91214782 0.88821773 0.86184514
[49] 0.83321504 0.80252824 0.77000000 0.73585847 0.70034314 0.66370312
[55] 0.62619540 0.58808309 0.54963351 0.51111636 0.47280181 0.43495860
[61] 0.39785218 0.36174283 0.32688382 0.29351967 0.26188441 0.23219992
[67] 0.20467443 0.17950101 0.15685623 0.13689893 0.11976909 0.10558687
[73] 0.09445175 0.08644182 0.08161328 0.08000000

> hamR(75) # the same as obtained by gsignal::hamming(76) in R
 [1] 0.08695652 0.08855761 0.09334964 0.10129899 0.11234992 0.12642490
 [7] 0.14342521 0.16323161 0.18570516 0.21068824 0.23800559 0.26746562
[13] 0.29886168 0.33197355 0.36656897 0.40240529 0.43923112 0.47678818
[19] 0.51481302 0.55303893 0.59119778 0.62902190 0.66624601 0.70260898
[25] 0.73785576 0.77173913 0.80402141 0.83447617 0.86288979 0.88906296
[31] 0.91281211 0.93397064 0.95239015 0.96794144 0.98051542 0.99002390
[37] 0.99640019 0.99959955 0.99959955 0.99640019 0.99002390 0.98051542
[43] 0.96794144 0.95239015 0.93397064 0.91281211 0.88906296 0.86288979
[49] 0.83447617 0.80402141 0.77173913 0.73785576 0.70260898 0.66624601
[55] 0.62902190 0.59119778 0.55303893 0.51481302 0.47678818 0.43923112
[61] 0.40240529 0.36656897 0.33197355 0.29886168 0.26746562 0.23800559
[67] 0.21068824 0.18570516 0.16323161 0.14342521 0.12642490 0.11234992
[73] 0.10129899 0.09334964 0.08855761 0.08695652
```

and we can check the lengths of resulting windows

```
> length(hamMatalb(75))
[1] 76

> length(hamR(75))
[1] 76
```

## Spectral Performance

Given `n <- 75`, we can take a look at the difference in the frequency domain, using `freqz`. We can see that the difference mainly lies in the stopband but still quite minor, which doesn't affect the filtering performance too much.

- `freqz(hamR(n))`

[image]

- `freqz(hamMatlab(n))`

[image]

Comment: +1, you beat me to this portion of the answer using the exact same links and nearly identical image of the algorithm. (I still think the core problem is that `gsignal::hamming(76)` produces different numbers than the OP posted. Perhaps if you extended your example to manually calculate for `n=76` and `n=77`, it would provide a little more insight.)

Comment: More reference for context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_and_Hamming_windows says *"Setting `a0` to approximately 0.54, or more precisely 25/46, produces the Hamming window, proposed by Richard W. Hamming."* This suggests Matlab is okay with *approximating*? (I'll duck whatever food fight that blasphemy incites ;-)

Comment: @r2evans yes, from the source code of `gsignal::hamming`, `hamming(77)` in R should be identical to `hamming(76)` in Matlab, but then the difference comes from the approximation.

Comment: Ahhh, so R does `N <- n-1` but Matlab does not? That's interesting ... yes, that makes sense too. Nice, thank you for correcting me!

Comment: thanks, so what shall i do to have the same output of Matlab?

Comment: @Tpellirn if you want to have the same output as in `MATLAB`, you can write your custom function, like `hamMatlab` in my updated answer. `hamming` window formula is simple, so, easy to write your own version if you don't rely on R's solution.

Comment: This is a really excellent answer. Do you have a view (or reference) about whether the differences between the R and MATLAB results are meaningful (in any domain)? Obviously we don't know the application in this case, but I've never used a Hamming window so have no idea if this something it's worth remembering in case one day it comes back to bite me...

Comment: @SamR from the perspective of spectral analysis, it difference is negligible. You can see my latest update with spectral analysis.

Comment: @r2evans AFAIK, Hamming himself suggested the rounded numbers, I guess that is why MATLAB uses them. 25/46 is where the first side-lobe gets cancelled, the exact solution to Hamming’s constraint. Using 0.53836 instead one gets the lowest side-lobes, which is actually better. The rounded value sits in between these two solutions. But the difference between them is minor, and not noticeable if you are using 8 bits for your signal.